# Reverse in Oracle this path z/y/x to x/y/z

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How would I do in a SELECT query to reverse this path :

```
z/y/x
```

for

```
x/y/z
```

where / is the delimiter
and where there can be many delimiters in a single line

```
ex: select (... z/y/x/w/v/u ...) reversed_path from ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to write a stored pl/sql function, however it can be done with SQL (Oracle) alone.

This will decompose the path in subpath:

```
SQL> variable path varchar2(4000);
SQL> exec :path := 'a/b/c/def';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
SQL> SELECT regexp_substr(:path, '[^/]+', 1, ROWNUM) sub_path, ROWNUM rk
  2    FROM dual
  3  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length(regexp_replace(:path, '[^/]', '')) + 1;

SUB_P RK
----- --
a      1
b      2
c      3
def    4
```

We then recompose the reversed path with the `sys_connect_by_path`:

```
SQL> SELECT MAX(sys_connect_by_path(sub_path, '/')) reversed_path
  2    FROM (SELECT regexp_substr(:path, '[^/]+', 1, ROWNUM) sub_path,
  3                 ROWNUM rk
  4             FROM dual
  5           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length(regexp_replace(:path, '[^/]', '')) + 1)
  6  CONNECT BY PRIOR rk = rk + 1
  7   START WITH rk = length(regexp_replace(:path, '[^/]', '')) + 1;

REVERSED_PATH
-------------
/def/c/b/a
```

Comment: REGEX was a new feature in 10g.

Comment: Thank you so much !! Did not know that Oracle had regex. I'm with 10g so I'm ok. Stackoverflow is great ! :-) I will tear this apart to try to master it monday when I arrive at the office (don't have vpn here!).

Answer (score 11):

You can get your result by connecting the reverted components, then reverting the resulting string again. Just make sure you strip your starting separator and put it on the other side:

```
SELECT '/' || REVERSE(LTRIM(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(REVERSE(x), '/'), '/') AS reversed_path
...
```

Comment: Correct my if I'm wrong but this would only work with names of 1 character length. But it's my mistake to not have given an more explicit example in the question I asked.

Comment: This is such a hacky solution, I laughed out loud when I first read it. But hey, it works. I would never have thought of this.

Answer (score 4):

```
select
    listagg(n.name,'\') within group (order by level desc)
 from nodes n
start with n.id = :childid
connect by prior n.parentid = n.id
order by level desc;
```

order by level desc. will concatenate the ancestors in the lineage first, since you are starting with the childid

Answer (score 3):

Found another solution [here](https://bitbach.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/implementing-bottom-up-path-traversal-for-hierarchical-tables/) that seems flexible, lean and I find quite easy to understand:

```sql
    SELECT son_id,
           dad_id,
           son_name,
           SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (son_name, '/') AS family_path
      FROM (    SELECT son_id,
                       dad_id,
                       son_name,
                       CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF AS cbleaf
                  FROM family
            START WITH son_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
            CONNECT BY PRIOR dad_id = son_id)
     WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH cbleaf = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR son_id = dad_id
```

Comment: clever : the connect by clause is inverted

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for REVERSE?
i.e

```
SELECT REVERSE('z/y/x') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: I looked it up - didn't know that REVERSE has been available since at least 8i.

Comment: This is cool, but it works only for path elements with 1 character.

Answer (score 0):

@Jean-Philippe Martin @OMG Ponies

Try this query,

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(PATH,'[^/]+',1,4) || '/' || REGEXP_SUBSTR(PATH,'[^/]+',1,3) || '/' || REGEXP_SUBSTR(PATH,'[^/]+',1,2) || '/' || REGEXP_SUBSTR(PATH,'[^/]+',1,1) "Reverse of Path" 
  FROM (SELECT 'a/bc/def/ghij' PATH FROM DUAL);
```

This will do it I guess :-)

Comment: Clever but I needed something generic for a variable number of sub-path. But your solution would work if the path level is fixed. tks

Comment: The answer is to the question you posted!! 

You didn't mention any generic variables of a sub-path in your question?!!

Even the answer provided by Vincent is a fixed variable path not a generic one!