# To select a column from a table using values from another table

Tags: ruby, oracle, rubygems, oracle10g, oracle11g

I have tables with columns as below:

**Employee:**

```
Id number(10),  
Name varchar2(10)
```

**Department:**

```
Id number(10),
Name varchar2(10),
Emp_ids varchar2(10)
```

The values present in the tables respectively are:

**Employee:**

```
1,abc,111
2,def,222
3,xyz,333
```

**Department:**

```
111,development,'1,2'
222,testing,'2,3'
```

My problem is that I need to select Employee Names using the `emp_ids` column from the Department table.

Example:

```
SELECT names FROM employee 
 WHERE id in (SELECT emp_ids FROM department WHERE name = 'development');
```

Since `emp_ids` is varchar2 datatype I am unable to execute the above command.

NOTE: As I am using `Activerecord Base Connection` to connect my Oracle DB from Ruby, I am including ruby in the tags too.

Comment: when you were running the code `SELECT names FROM employee WHERE id in (SELECT emp_ids FROM department WHERE name = 'development');`, what did you get?

Comment: I am facing datatype mismatch error: **ORA-01722: invalid number**

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert csv to table in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142665/how-to-convert-csv-to-table-in-oracle)

Comment: That's because '1,2' is a string and isn't a valid number.  Basically you have a CSV which you need to split into separate tokens.  There's *loads* of examples of how to this on SO.  Check out the suggested duplicate for workarounds.

Comment: As an aside, storing values like this is *a really bad idea*.  Even worse than a nested table column.  Use a relational approach such as an intersection table, or use the standard solution: DEPT_ID as a foreign key on EMPLOYEE.

Comment: As you apperently have an N:N relationship the interasection table is the only viable approach (although haveing employees work for two departments simultaneously will create some interesting clashes when salary appraisal time comes around).

Comment: This is clearly a case for an intersection table: what a rubyist would call a "has_many through", or maybe a has_and_belongs_to_many.

Answer (score 2):

**Your data model is not properly designed**. You *could* build a query that would work but it would be:

1. more complex than needed,
2. eventually inefficient as your data grows in size,
3. open to inconsistency because you can't define referential constraints properly,
4. most certainly vendor specific.

I suggest you use a reliable data model. You have a N-N relationship, you **need** three tables:

```
Employee (Id number(10) primary key, Name varchar2(10))
Department (Id number(10) primary key,Name varchar2(10))

Employee_department (
   emp_id number(10) references employee (id),
   dep_id number(10) references department(id),
   constraint pk_emp_dept primary key (emp_id, dep_id)
)
```

Then your query will work flawlessly, efficiently and you won't lose sleep at night regarding data inconsistency.

```
SELECT names 
  FROM employee 
 WHERE id in (SELECT ed.emp_id 
                FROM department d
                JOIN employee_department ed ON d.id = ed.dep_id
               WHERE d.name = 'development');
```

As a database developer your two main goals are:

- To make sure data is properly saved to the database. Nothing else is more important than the data. If you can't trust your data, what good is a database? Eliminating inconsistencies is a top priority.
- To make a bug-free application. If your model is appropriate, your queries will be simpler, you will make less bugs, your applications will be faster and in general more reliable.

Comment: Yes Vincent you are right but my company has designed to implement like that. And our customer has asked to bring a solution with a possible query

Comment: @kattashri there are many ways to convert a "csv" type list of values to a view, for example using [a technique from another SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381256/reverse-in-oracle-this-path-z-y-x-to-x-y-z). However I must stress that it is a workaround due to a poor choice in data model. You should always strive to defend the most appropriate data model because it will make data management easier and applications in general more reliable :)

Comment: @kattashri With all due respect - then your company should re-consider its choice of the data model. What are the reasons your company wants to use a csv list instead of the standard intersection table?

Comment: Time to start looking for a competent company to work for, if this is how they build their systems. There's a world of hurt coming up for this.

Comment: Just a note to say that as this is a ruby & activerecord system, the columns for the join table would conventionally be id as the primary key, and employee_id and department_id as the foreign keys (with a composite unique key on them, preferably, and not nulls)

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you change your table structure.

**Employee:**

```
   id 
   name
   dept_id
```

**Department:**

```
   id 
   name
```

Comment: This doesn't reflect the business rules represented by the posted data

Comment: `declare @ids nvarchar(50)
declare @strsql nvarchar(500)

select @ids = Emp_IDS from tblDepartment  where depName='dev'

set @ids='''' + REPLACE(@ids,',',''',''')  + ''''

set @strsql = 'SELECT name FROM tblemployee 
 WHERE convert(nvarchar,id) in ( ' +  @ids + ' )'
 
exec sp_executesql @strsql`