# SQL to reverse the path (eg. abc/def/ghi to ghi/def/abc)

Tags: oracle, reverse

I have trying to figure out how to reverse the path of a result. Suppose the result path is abc/def/ghi , so i need to reverse it so the result is read as "ghi/def/abc".

I have searched for this and there was one solution by Vincent ([Reverse in Oracle this path z/y/x to x/y/z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381256/reverse-in-oracle-this-path-z-y-x-to-x-y-z/24333006#24333006)).

However when I tried to do the same , I get an error "argument '0' is out of range".

Below is what I did:

```
    SQL> variable path varchar2(4000); SQL> exec :path := 'a/b/c/def';

    PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
    path

    a/b/c/def

    SQL> SELECT regexp_substr(:path, '[^/]+', 1, ROWNUM) sub_path, ROWNUM rk 2 from dual 3 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length(regexp_replace(:path, '[^/]', '')) + 1;

    SUB_PATH RK

    a 1 b 2 c 3 def 4
    path

a/b/c/def

    SQL> SELECT MAX(sys_connect_by_path(sub_path, '/')) reversed_path 2 FROM (SELECT regexp_substr(:path, '[^/]+', 1, ROWNUM) sub_path, 3 ROWNUM rk 4 FROM dual 5 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length(regexp_replace(:path, '[^/]', '')) + 1) 6 CONNECT BY PRIOR rk = rk + 1 7 START WITH rk = length(regexp_replace(:path, '[^/]', '')) + 1;

    ORA-01428: argument '0' is out of range
    path

a/b/c/def
```

I tried but having a hard time to figure out the reason for this error. Once I am able to understand then maybe I can use this for my query to generate revers path. FYI, REVERSE function wont work since it only reverses character which is not the desired result.

Any help or hint is much appreciated. Thanks much!!

Comment: Worked for me in a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6023b/3

Answer (score 0):

@Joe thanks much!!
SQL Fiddle helped me to reach the answer though I wasn't able to figure out the solution but the below query provided the result I needed.

```
SELECT MAX(sys_connect_by_path(sub_path, '/')) reversed_path 
FROM 
(SELECT regexp_substr(:path, '[^/]+', 1, ROWNUM) sub_path,  
ROWNUM rk  FROM duh  
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length(regexp_replace(:path, '[^/]', '')) + 1) 
CONNECT BY PRIOR rk = rk + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3761113

Try this query,

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(PATH,'[^/]+',1,4) || '/' || REGEXP_SUBSTR(PATH,'[^/]+',1,3) || '/' || REGEXP_SUBSTR(PATH,'[^/]+',1,2) || '/' || REGEXP_SUBSTR(PATH,'[^/]+',1,1) "Reverse of Path" 
  FROM (SELECT 'a/bc/def/ghij' PATH FROM DUAL);
```

This will do it I guess :-)